# Read content of file from Data Lake Store using C# code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to read the content from the Azure Data Lake Store file. But while connecting / opening the connection itself fails & exception is thrown

```
 var stream = _adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(_adlsAccountName, "/folder1/"+file.PathSuffix);
```

Getting exception as:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.
```

Unable to recognize the issue.
How to resolve this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException' was thrown.

It is  basic exception info. So please have a try to use fiddler tool to catch the detail error info.

According to your code, it seems that file is not found or authorization exception.

1.If it is 404 error: Please a try to use the following format and check the file from the azure portal.

```
 var srcPath = "/mytempdir/tomtest.txt";
 var stream = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(adlsAccountName, srcPath);
```

[image]

2.If it is the authorization exception and if you are using service-to-service authentication with client secret. Please assign permission to the azure AD Application to operate the file. More details please refer to the [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-authenticate-using-active-directory.md).

[image]

[image]

The following is my test code and screenshot:

```
 var applicationId = "your application Id";
 var secretKey = "secret Key";
 var tenantId = "Your tenantId";
 var adlsAccountName = "adls account name";
 var creds = ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, applicationId, secretKey).Result;
 var adlsFileSystemClient = new DataLakeStoreFileSystemManagementClient(creds);
 var srcPath = "/mytempdir/tomtest.txt";
 var destPath = @"F:\tom\testfile.txt";
 using (var stream = adlsFileSystemClient.FileSystem.Open(adlsAccountName, srcPath))
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(destPath, FileMode.Create))
 {
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
 }
```

[image]

Packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store" version="1.0.4" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreFileSystem" version="0.9.6-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.StoreUploader" version="1.0.1-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.2.12" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thank you...Tom Sun....I got the problem resolved. Actually I provided access to AAD as "Reader" in ADLS via "Access Control(IAM)". Since then the code started working correctly.

Comment: I want to read the content of the file and get the first row /line in a string.  The documentation has example of copying from one destination to another. I want to copy file, only if the content from the file is in correct format. Have to add this condition, so How do I get/read the content from file?