# Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException was thrown when trying to open file from Data Lake store

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I have a big file on Data Lake store, size is 35GB. I m trying to open just a little part of it, with .net SDK method

`public static Task<Stream> OpenAsync(this IFileSystemOperations operations, string accountName, string directFilePath, long? length = null, long? offset = null, Guid? fileSessionId = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken));`

where I put my length to be 2mb or 2097152 bytes and offset to almost 35gb 37580963840 bytes. When I run the application it throws Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException without any inner exception and stack trace is not of big use. Does anybody know something about this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably authorization failure, have you provided the aad with "read"  access permissions (datalake => IAM (Access Control))

Comment: I can use that file from SSIS package, so I don't think its permission. I m using that directory in other projects too, so something else is the problem. I suspect on the size of the file...

Comment: also look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926878/read-content-of-file-from-data-lake-store-using-c-sharp-code